# Convert PHP code to Vb.net

Tags: php, vb.net

i am facing an issue with vb.net about how to put the data in the multidimensional  array and loop through it and print the result to string

now i solve it in php  but i can't do it in vb.net i am not familiar  with vb.net also the multidimensional  arrays

**this my PHP script**

```
$first_dimensionarray = array();//empty array
            $second_dimensionarray = array();//empty array
            for($i = 0; $i < count ( $data); $i ++){
            //loop through the data
            $second_dimensionarray = array(strtotime($data['date']),  $data['name']  , $data['phone'] , $data['email'] ,$data['date']  );//put every record as array in second_dimensionarray
            array_push( $first_dimensionarray, $second_dimensionarray ); //push second_dimensionarray inside the first_dimensionarray 
            }
            sort( $first_dimensionarray ); //sort $first_dimensionarray by the first element   >> (strtotime($data['date'])
            $arraycheck = array(); //another array to put the names into it
            for($i = 0; $i < count ( $first_dimensionarray ); $i ++)// loop through the new dimensional array --first_dimensionarray
            { 
                if(!in_array($first_dimensionarray[$i][1],$arraycheck ))//check if name exsit in arraycheck 
                {     
                        $arraycheck[] =$first_dimensionarray[$i][1];// if not then add it to arraycheck 
                        unset($first_dimensionarray[$i][0]);//remove the first index (the purpose for this element (date) is to sort all Data by  date)
                        $string .= implode( ",", $first_dimensionarray[$i] );
                        $string .= "\n";

                }
            }
```

**this is what i tried in vb.net**

```
   For i = 0 To ata.Count 
              second_dimensionarray(i) = (strtotime($data('date')),$data('name'),$data('phone'),$data('email'),$data('date')}
              Array.Copy(second_dimensionarray, first_dimensionarray, 13)
              Next i
```

**please can anyone help me rewriteing this php code in vb.net ?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your data is being provided by so I just used a DataTable as an example. First, create a class (or structure). The VB compiler will create the getter and setter and backer field for each property. Of course, you can spell it out if you need code in the getter or setter. A default constructor will also be created.
If you use a generic list instead of an array, you do not need to define the size.  Loop through your data, first creating a new instance of your class then assigning the values the properties. Then add the instance to the list. Once you have your list you can sort and access properties easily.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub ConvertPHP()
        Dim strData As DataTable
    Dim lstPerson As New List(Of Person)
    For i As Integer = 0 To strData.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim p As New Person()
        p.Time = CDate(strData.Rows(i)("date")).ToShortTimeString
        p.Name = strData.Rows(i)("name").ToString
        p.Phone = strData.Rows(i)("phone").ToString
        p.Email = strData.Rows(i)("email").ToString
        p.PDate = CDate(strData.Rows(i)("date"))
        p.Children = {"Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"}
        lstPerson.Add(p)
    Next
    Debug.Print(lstPerson.Item(0).Children(0))
    Dim lstSortedByName As List(Of Person) = lstPerson.OrderBy(Function(p) p.Name).ToList
    For i As Integer = 0 To lstPerson.Count - 1
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lstPerson.Item(0).Name) Then
            'Do something
        End If
    Next
End Sub
End Class
Class Person
    Public Property Time As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Phone As String
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property PDate As DateTime
    Public Property Children As String()
End Class
```

Comment: thanks for your response but i have a question ,how can i add an array of element in this line  lstPerson.Add(p) ... like this                                For index = 0 To 4
            Dim students(4) As String
            students(0) = "asd"
            students(1) = "asd@ytg.xcom"
            students(2) = "1313123"
            students(3) = "2/2/1210"
            students(4) = "12345"
            al.Add(students)
        Next

Comment: I added an array property to the class and the example. HTH